# In D3 hexbin, increase radius of multiple hexagons with mouseover

Tags: javascript, d3.js

EDIT: And [here is a link to a codepen of mine](https://codepen.io/canovice/pen/deXgWP) where I have the simpler hover functionality working.

I am new to D3 and trying to create a fairly tricky hover effect on a hexbin graph. I attached the image of the hexes below to describe my effect.

[image]

An individual hexagon in a hex graph like this (unless its on the edge) borders 6 other hexagons. My goal is that when a user hovers over a hex, the radius of **both** that hex, as well as the 6 surrounding hexes, increases, to give a sort of pop up effect.

Using [Bostocks starter hexbin code here](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4248145) and adjusting it a bit (adding a radiusScale and hover effect), I made the following code snippet below that has a simpler hover effect:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

const randomX = d3.randomNormal(width / 2, 80),
    randomY = d3.randomNormal(height / 2, 80),
    points = d3.range(2000).map(function() { return [randomX(), randomY()]; });

const color = d3.scaleSequential(d3.interpolateLab("white", "steelblue"))
    .domain([0, 20]);

const hexbin = d3.hexbin()
    .radius(20)
    .extent([[0, 0], [width, height]]);

const x = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, width])
    .range([0, width]);

const y = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, height])
    .range([height, 0]);

// radiusScale
const radiusScale = d3.scaleSqrt()
    .domain([0, 10]) // domain is # elements in hexbin
    .range([0, 8]);  // range is mapping to pixels (or coords) for radius


g.append("clipPath")
    .attr("id", "clip")
  .append("rect")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

g.append("g")
    .attr("class", "hexagon")
    .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
  .selectAll("path")
  .data(hexbin(points))
  .enter().append("path")
    .attr("d", d => hexbin.hexagon(radiusScale(d.length))) 
    // .attr("d", hexbin.hexagon()) 
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; })
    .attr("fill", function(d) { return color(d.length); })
  .on('mouseover', function(d) { 
        d3.select(this)
          .attr("d", d => hexbin.hexagon(radiusScale((5+d.length)*2)))
  })
  .on('mouseout', function(d) { 
        d3.select(this)
          .attr("d", d => hexbin.hexagon(radiusScale(d.length)))
  })

  g.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis axis--y")
      .call(d3.axisLeft(y).tickSizeOuter(-width));

  g.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x).tickSizeOuter(-height));
```

```css
.hexagon {
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 0.5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.13.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-hexbin.v0.2.min.js"></script>
<svg width="500" height="400"></svg>
```

This effect only increases the radius of the single hexagon being hovered over, not also the surrounding hexagons.

To begin addressing the issue of increasing the radius of surrounding hexagons, I wrote this function that takes the binned data, an (x,y) location (center of a hexagon), and a radius that is wide enough to capture the (x,y) centers of neighbor hexagons:

```
// hexbinData, which was created using the hexbin() function, 
// has a .x and .y value for each element, and the .x and .y values 
// represent the center of that hexagon.

const findNeighborHexs = function(hexbinData, xHex, yHex, radius) {
  var neighborHexs = hexbinData
    .filter(row => row.x < (xHex+radius) & row.x > (xHex-radius))
    .filter(row => row.y < (yHex+radius) & row.y > (yHex-radius))

  return neighborHexs;
}
```

And here is where I'm stuck... I'm not sure how to use findNeighborHexs to (1) select those elements on hovering and (2) change those elements sizes. As a very tough (3), I think I may need to move the (x,y) centers for these neighbox hexes too to account for larger radius.

Thanks in advance for any help with this. I know this is a long post but I've got a bunch of stuff done already for this and this would be a very cool hover effect I'm working on so any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a slightly modified version of your code which also plays with adjacent hexagons of the hovered hexagon:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

const randomX = d3.randomNormal(width / 2, 80),
    randomY = d3.randomNormal(height / 2, 80),
    points = d3.range(2000).map(function() { return [randomX(), randomY()]; });

const color = d3.scaleSequential(d3.interpolateLab("white", "steelblue"))
    .domain([0, 20]);

const hexbin = d3.hexbin()
    .radius(20)
    .extent([[0, 0], [width, height]]);

const x = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, width])
    .range([0, width]);

const y = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, height])
    .range([height, 0]);

// radiusScale
const radiusScale = d3.scaleSqrt()
    .domain([0, 10]) // domain is # elements in hexbin
    .range([0, 8]);  // range is mapping to pixels (or coords) for radius

g.append("clipPath")
    .attr("id", "clip")
  .append("rect")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

function unique(arr) {
    var u = {}, a = [];
    for(var i = 0, l = arr.length; i < l; ++i){
        if(!u.hasOwnProperty(arr[i])) {
            a.push(arr[i]);
            u[arr[i]] = 1;
        }
    }
    return a;
}

var xs = unique(hexbin(points).map(h => parseFloat(h.x))).sort(function(a,b) { return a - b;});
var ys = unique(hexbin(points).map(h => parseFloat(h.y))).sort(function(a,b) { return a - b;});

g.append("g")
    .attr("class", "hexagon")
    .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
  .selectAll("path")
  .data(hexbin(points))
  .enter().append("path")
    .attr("id", d => xs.indexOf(d.x) + "-" + ys.indexOf(d.y))
    .attr("length", d => d.length)
    .attr("d", d => hexbin.hexagon(radiusScale(d.length)))
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
     return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
    })
    .attr("fill", function(d) { return color(d.length); })
  .on('mouseover', function(d) {

    d3.select(this).attr("d", d => hexbin.hexagon(radiusScale((5 + d.length) * 2)));

    var dx = xs.indexOf(d.x);
    var dy = ys.indexOf(d.y);

    [[-2, 0], [-1, -1], [1, -1], [2, 0], [1, 1], [-1, 1]].forEach( neighbour => {
      var elmt = document.getElementById((dx + neighbour[0]) + "-" + (dy + neighbour[1]))
      if (elmt) {
        var elmtLength = parseInt(elmt.getAttribute("length"));
        elmt.setAttribute("d", hexbin.hexagon(radiusScale(5 + elmtLength)));
      }
    });
  })
  .on('mouseout', function(d) {

    d3.select(this).attr("d", d => hexbin.hexagon(radiusScale(d.length)));

    var dx = xs.indexOf(d.x);
    var dy = ys.indexOf(d.y);

    [[-2, 0], [-1, -1], [1, -1], [2, 0], [1, 1], [-1, 1]].forEach( neighbour => {
      var elmt = document.getElementById((dx + neighbour[0]) + "-" + (dy + neighbour[1]))
      if (elmt) {
        var elmtLength = parseInt(elmt.getAttribute("length"));
        elmt.setAttribute("d", hexbin.hexagon(radiusScale(elmtLength)));
      }
    });
  })

  g.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis axis--y")
      .call(d3.axisLeft(y).tickSizeOuter(-width));

  g.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x).tickSizeOuter(-height));
```

```css
.hexagon {
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 0.5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.13.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-hexbin.v0.2.min.js"></script>
<svg width="500" height="400"></svg>
```

---

The idea is to give each hexagon an `id` in order to be able to select it.

If the hexagon being hovered is the 6th from the left and the 3rd from the top, then we can give it the `id` `#6-3`.

This way when this hexagon is hovered, we can play with its adjacent hexagons by selecting them by their `id`, the one on its left for instance has the `id` `#5-3`.

---

In order to give each hexagon an `id`, as d3's `hexbin(input)` replaces our input with only the hexagons' `x` and `y` coordinates, we'll have to find find all `x`s and `y`s produced:

```
var xs = unique(hexbin(points).map(h => parseFloat(h.x))).sort(function(a,b) { return a - b;});
var ys = unique(hexbin(points).map(h => parseFloat(h.y))).sort(function(a,b) { return a - b;});
```

where `unique` is whatever function keeping only distinct values.

This way, our hexagons can be given an `id` this way:

```
...
.data(hexbin(points))
  .enter().append("path")
  .attr("id", d => xs.indexOf(d.x) + "-" + ys.indexOf(d.y))
  ...
```

---

Now that our hexagons have an `id`, we can modify our `mouseover` and `mouseout` to play with these adjacent hexagons:

Adjacent hexagons are the ones for which we need to sum x and y of the hovered hexagon by:

```
[[-2, 0], [-1, -1], [1, -1], [2, 0], [1, 1], [-1, 1]]
```

which gives for the `mouseover` (in addition to modifying the size of the hovered hexagon):

```
.on('mouseover', function(d) {

  d3.select(this).attr("d", d => hexbin.hexagon(radiusScale((5 + d.length) * 2)));

  var dx = xs.indexOf(d.x);
  var dy = ys.indexOf(d.y);

  [[-2, 0], [-1, -1], [1, -1], [2, 0], [1, 1], [-1, 1]].forEach( neighbour => {
    var elmt = document.getElementById((dx + neighbour[0]) + "-" + (dy + neighbour[1]))
    if (elmt) {
      var elmtLength = parseInt(elmt.getAttribute("length"));
      elmt.setAttribute("d", hexbin.hexagon(radiusScale(5 + elmtLength)));
    }
  });
})
```

---

Note that in addition to setting the `id` of each hexagon, we also include the `length` attribute in order to easily change the hovered size of hexagons.

Answer (score 2):

you could amend you mouseover and mouseout functions to be the following, which selects all the hexagons and sets the size based on whether they fall within your defined radius:

```
.on('mouseover', function(d) {
        let dx = d.x
        let dy = d.y
        let r = 50 //set this to be an appropriate size radius

        d3.selectAll(".hexagon").selectAll("path")
          .attr("d", function(f) {
              if ((f.x < (dx + r) & f.x > (dx - r)) &  (f.y < (dy + r) & f.y > (dy - r)))  {
                return hexbin.hexagon(radiusScale((5+f.length)*2))
              }
              else {
                return hexbin.hexagon(radiusScale((f.length)))
              }
          })


  })
  .on('mouseout', function(d) { 
         d3.selectAll(".hexagon").selectAll("path")
          .attr("d", d => hexbin.hexagon(radiusScale(d.length)))
  })
```